# How to make gradient background in Kivy

Tags: python, background, kivy, gradient

I am trying to create an app with gradient background and label in Kivy. I googled and found this for gradient background, but it is only widget and when I trying to put label there it is not working. Code:

```
from kivy.app import App, runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**args)
        self.texture = Texture.create(size=(2, 2), colorfmt='rgba')
        p1_color = [173, 0, 255, 255]
        p2_color = [253, 0, 243, 255]
        p3_color = [173, 0, 255, 255]
        p4_color = [253, 0, 243, 255]
        p = p1_color + p2_color + p3_color + p4_color
        buf = bytes(p)
        self.texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgba', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size, texture=self.texture)

        self.bind(size=self.update_rect)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.size = self.size
        self.rect.pos = self.pos


runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
MyWidget:
'''))
```

From this code, I tried to create an app with gradient background, but it is black(

```
from kivy.app import App, runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.texture = Texture.create(size=(2, 2), colorfmt='rgba')
        p1_color = [173, 0, 255, 255]
        p2_color = [253, 0, 243, 255]
        p3_color = [173, 0, 255, 255]
        p4_color = [253, 0, 243, 255]
        p = p1_color + p2_color + p3_color + p4_color
        buf = bytes(p)
        self.texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgba', bufferfmt='ubyte')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Over background I need to create a label, but I don't know why I can't(
Help please)

Comment: Maybe you should research a bit more if you are new to this instead of completly copying a project. If you want people to help you, please provide more information of what you have done and how people would be able to help you.

Comment: @darclander I googled a lot, almost a week, but can't find something that will help me(

Comment: I do not think that stackoverflow is here to help you program, but if you go to my [github](https://github.com/darclander) and add my discord I could try to help you.

Comment: Your modified code is just a black window because you didn't write any code that would display the texture. Try starting from the original example and modifying it step by step, instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: @inclement Thank's, I will try)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to solving this problem can be using `Color` and `Line` in the canvas of background layout.

In order to make a gradient effect, I added as many vertical lines as the application window width to the background which is a BoxLayout in my case. In every iteration, the variable of `alpha_channel_rate` has been increased. And that makes the gradient effect.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Background(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Background, self).__init__()
        self.width = Window.size[0]
        self.height = Window.size[1]
        self.add_gradient()

    def add_gradient(self):
        alpha_channel_rate = 0
        increase_rate = 1 / self.width

        for sep in range(self.width):
            self.canvas.add(Color(rgba=(0, 1, 0, alpha_channel_rate)))
            self.canvas.add(Line(points=[sep, 0, sep, self.height], width=1))
            alpha_channel_rate += increase_rate


class GradientApp(App):
    def build(self):
        background = Background()
        return background


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GradientApp().run()
```

The output of the program is like this:
[image]

Maybe you can create some other functionality that you want using this method. For instance, a radial gradient effect also can be created using the `Circle` method of the `kivy.graphics`.

On the other hand, the lines and color objects can be dynamic using the bind method as you did in your program, and also some gradient groups can be created using canvas instructions in order to edit some canvas objects in later times.

Comment: Try to resize the window) The gradient will be smaller than the window)

Comment: Yes, it is because of not updating the line sizes and line positions dynamically as I mentioned in my solution. I just showed an approach to how can be a gradient effect made. However, you can update the line sizes and line positions as you did like the 'update_rect' method in your code.

Comment: Is it possible only with black color? (Green I can change)

Comment: Sure you can change the color. Also you can check the official website of Kivy for more information about coloring (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.context_instructions.html). And according to what you want to achieve, you need to manipulate the `add_gradient` method in my case. So you can combine other colors as well.

Answer (score 4):

check this repo out https://github.com/kengoon/KivyGradient or you can quickly install it by
`pip install kivygradient`