# How to make a scalable gradient in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, gradient

I want to have a **gradient color** as the background of my app and I also want it to be **scalable and animatable**. I have checked other links on how to do this and the results were not really interesting.

One stackoverflow issue suggested to fill the entire program with lines and change their properties but isn't that too bloated and also what if they resize the program? You either have to resize all the lines or add or remove them based on the size.

There was only one post that I found on github and it seems to work but I don't understand it and also I don't know if it is animatable and sometimes creates black spaces before updating the screen and resizing.

I visited the kivy docs and made a texture based on the doc but the gradient was chopped in half and it was replaced by some absurd lines. Also when resizing, the quality of the texture dropped.

Here is the link to the relatively working gradient on github: https://gist.github.com/gottadiveintopython/d9a2935560469bd8a8d0a890180003c7

link to inefficient approach on stackoverflow in case you want to have a look:

[How to make gradient background in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63753600/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-kivy)

The code using kivy.graphics.texture.Texture:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window


# Exact copy of the docs
texture = Texture.create(size=(64, 64))
size = 64 * 64 * 3
buf = [int(x * 255 / size) for x in range(size)]
buf = ''.join(map(chr, buf)).encode("utf-8")
texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
Builder.load_string('''
<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                texture: root.texture_obj''')


class MyLayout(Widget):
    texture_obj = ObjectProperty(texture)


class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

The result of the code:
[image: Weird kivy gradient result]

As a side note, I also do not want to use images and by animatable I mean that at the beginning of the app I want the gradient to start from one side and expand to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [documentaation](https://kivy.org/doc/master/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#blitting-custom-data) says to use:

```
buf = bytes(buf)
```

instead of:

```
buf = ''.join(map(chr, buf)).encode("utf-8")
```

I believe that will fix your problem.

If you want to adjust how much of the gradient is black, just modify the calculation of the pixels. For example:

```
texture = Texture.create(size=(64, 64))
size = 64 * 64 * 3

def pixel(x, size, factor):
    p = max( 0, int(255 * (factor * x - (factor - 1) * size) / size))
    return p

buf = [pixel(x, size, 2) for x in range(size)]
buf = bytes(buf)
texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
```

The above code uses a `pixel()` method to calculate the pixel values. The `factor` argument specifies how much of the gradient will not be black. So, with `factor` set to `2` (as in the above code) only the top half of the gradient will not be black. Similarly, a value of `3` results in only the top third not being black. The `factor` must not be less than zero. A `factor` of `1` produces the original gradient and a `factor` of `0` produces no gradient (all white).

Comment: it worked, however, how can I change the color and the length of the gradient itself? I can change the rectangle color which would change the color it fades out in but how can I modify the beginning? Thanks by the way

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question. the `Color:` changes the color, but what do you mean by the length of the gradient?

Comment: What should I do to make the black gradient take up a larger portion of the texture?